# how to concatenate data from json with "this.props" in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create Textfields dynamically through data json, the problem raises when I want to set a value and onChange function to each field.

I tried to use string but I didnt work

value={`${this.state}.`+ `${textfield.label}`}

value={`this.state.${textfield.label}`}

```
 this.state = {     
  label1: "",
  label2 : ""     
};
```

}

```
{textfields.map((textfield) => {
return(
      <TextField
      key={textfield.label}
      label={textfield.name}
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      id={textfield.label}
      required
      value={`${this.state}.`+ `${textfield.label}`}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ `${textfield.label}` : e.target.value })}
      />
      )
  })
}
```

the problem is with value and onChange

I expect 
value={this.state.label1}
value={this.state.label2}

onChange={e => this.setState({ label1 : e.target.value })}
onChange={e => this.setState({ label2 : e.target.value })}

I got
value=[object Object].label1
value=[object Object].label2

or
value="this.state.label1" but as string in texfield
value="this.state.label1" but as string in texfield

onChange shows syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use plain JavaScript inside your curly braces. Like so:

```
 value={this.state[textfield.label]}
```

Comment: value={this.state[textfield.label]} and onChange={e => this.setState({ [textfield.label] : e.target.value })}

Answer (score 0):

Can you throw a name with it like this?

{textfields.map((textfield) => {

```
return(
      <TextField
      key={textfield.label}
      label={textfield.name}
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth
      id={textfield.label}
      required
    name={textfield.label}
      value={`${this.state}.`+ `${textfield.label}`}
      onChange={e => this.setState({ `e.target.name` : e.target.value })}
      />
      )
  })
}
```

Comment: yes, but react shows Parsing error: Unexpected token at the first  ` from `e.target.name`